# ElasticSearch DSL -> Combine multiple filters and eliminate metadata

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

The following query is suppose to return the documents where the product_id is 12.

```
request = Search(using=client, index='myIndex') \
            .filter("match",product_id=12) \
            .source(myFieldsArray)
```

Now i would like to also cut out all documents where `parent` is null.
I would like also that the metadata not be returned, only the actual data  (on kopf i use `filter_path=hits.hits._source.*` on the query string)

How can i do these on elastic search-dsl?

Details: using Elasticsearch 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filters can be chained, just `.filter(` away. In order to eliminate metadata you must set the `params` like `.params(filter_path="hits.hits._source.*")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `parent` is a field of document and by metadata you mean `_source`. For first condition

> cut out all documents where `parent` is null

You have to use [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#find-docs-null-values) inside `must_not` clause. For

> metadata not be returned

You have to set `"_source": false`

Query translate as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "product_id": 12
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "parent"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```